# Delete the current element in an array

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

How can I delete the current element of an array inside a foreach-loop?

My program gets data form a DB and sends it to a new one via HTTP requests. Now I want to post a JSON string to my new DB. If it was a success I want to delete the current array item which I'm working with. Something like this.

```
foreach(var item in array)
{
    bool decide = method.DoSomething();
    if(decide == true)
    {
        //delete current item
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful. If you delete the current element, your application will throw an exception as you are looping through the array

Comment: Arrays have fixed length. You can't "delete" items from them. You have to create a *copy* of the array with just the items you want. That's expensive. What are you actually trying to do and how frequent are deletions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are 2 ways (both were tested)

```
foreach (var item in array.ToList())
    {
         bool decide = method.DoSomething();
        if (decide == true)
        {
            item.Remove();
        }
    }
```

and

```
for ( i=0; i <  array.Length; i++) 
    {
         bool decide = method.DoSomething();
        if (decide == true)
        {
            array[i].Remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are calling `Remove` on the item in the collection.

Answer (score 8):

since you cannot delete items from an array and change the size of it here is a loop approach using a second collection

```
List<itemClass> keepCollection = new List<itemClass>();

foreach(var item in array)
{
    bool decide = method.DoSomething();
    if(decide == false)
    {
        keepCollection.Add(item);
    }
}
```

If you need it again in array form just call `ToArray()`

```
var finalResult = keepCollection.ToArray();
```

Comment: Safest approach

Answer (score 3):

appraoch with Linq which creates a new array with valid elements and overwrites the existing array

```
array = array.Where(x => !method.DoSomething(x)).ToArray(); //select valid elements
```

Comment: That's a great way to solve this with a single line. But the user explicitly asked for a deletion inside a **foreach-loop**. Please read the question carefully next time! nice du hast zur leet-time kommentiert :D

Comment: @Csharpest lmao, `Where()` uses internally loops

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to delete entries from a collection, you should never loop through that collection from beginning to end, but always from end back to beginning.

By the way, C# does not allow you deleting entries from a collection while looping through that collection using a `foreach` loop.